# Unable to run Slither after installation. ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, slither

Although I have no problems when installing slither using `pip3 install slither-analyzer`, I am unable to run it . This is the error messgae I get when doing it:

```
PS C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\slither> slither .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\slither\slither.py", line 7, in <module>
    from slither.core.compilation_unit import SlitherCompilationUnit
  File "C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\slither\slither.py", line 7, in <module>
    from slither.core.compilation_unit import SlitherCompilationUnit
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slither.core'; 'slither' is not a package
```

I am already trying to run it from the result or running npm-which slither:

```
C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\slither\slither.PY
```

These are the logs of the installation:

```
PS C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\slither> pip3 install slither-analyzer
Requirement already satisfied: slither-analyzer in c:\users\pablo\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages\slither_analyzer-0.8.3-py3.10.egg (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: prettytable>=0.7.2 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from slither-analyzer) (3.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pysha3>=1.0.2 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from slither-analyzer) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: crytic-compile in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from slither-analyzer) (0.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from prettytable>=0.7.2->slither-analyzer) (0.2.5)
```

As far as I see, the installation has gone correctly. What am I missing?

Also, when I try to run the **Remix IDE (desktop) slither extension**, it refuses to do so:

```
{"type":"error","value":"[Slither Analysis]: Error occured! See remixd console for details."}
```

Thanks in advance for your replies.